# ionic firebase auto phone auth does not change the auth state

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins, ionic5

auth state never don't change event after a user has been signed in with firebase phone auto auth for android.

the behavior on a not android device is as expected

```js
async signinWithPhone(phoneNumber){
    const loading =  await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      keyboardClose: false,
      animated: true,
      spinner: 'lines',
      backdropDismiss: false,
    })
    await loading.present()
    this.auth.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 120000).then(async verificationId => {
      loading.dismiss()
      const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Verify phone number',
        message: 'Please provide the SMS code you received on your phone.',
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'code',
            type: 'tel',
            placeholder: 'SMS Code'
          },
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            cssClass: 'secondary',
          }, {
            text: 'Okay',
            handler: (data) => {
              loading.present()
              this.auth.signInWithVerificationId(verificationId, data.code).then(async res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.toast.show('Signed in')
                this.router.navigate(['home'])
              })
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      await alert.present();
    }).catch(async err => {
      this.toast.show(err, 'danger')
      console.log(err);
      loading.dismiss()
    })
  }
```

this is the user state observable subscription.

```js
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe(user => {
        console.log(user)
      if(user){
        this.user.next(user)
        this.router.navigate(['home', 'menu'])
      } else{
        this.user.next(null)
        this.router.navigate(['login'])
      }
    })
```

I can't find any solution online, i'm not that familiar with how this works on the base side of it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see your signing-in log when logging in?

Comment: Yeah I have a console.log(user) inside the if block

Comment: I mean does it show on you android console

Comment: just checked cant see that there neither

Comment: You need to set up logs through out your code to identify where it block

Comment: it has logs i just removed it from here. the log stops before it goes into the .then block on verifyPhoneNumber

Comment: you need to dig there, more logs !